# About imgradient function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having doubt to the used equation in the function of `imgradient`.
In the line of 127:

> ```
>     Gdir = atan2(-Gy,Gx)*180/pi; % Radians to degrees
> ```

Why the `Gy` have to be negative?

Comment: It forces it to be in the 4th quadrant: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#buct8h0-4. why you need to force it to be in the 4th quadrant I have no idea.

Comment: @Dan: It forces it to the 4th quadrant if it was in the 1st.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I meant I don't know why you need to do that in terms of the logic of the `imgradient` function, as in I'm not sure if the OP is asking what the `-` does or why in terms of the logic of the function it is necessary to make sure `Gdir` is in the 4th quad (although that actually is assuming `Gy` and `Gx` are both positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The y-axis is inverted in images (it increases downward instead of upward). This causes the angles to increase clockwise instead of counter-clockwise as you're used to. By flipping the y component of the gradient, this line computes an angle in the "normal" sense.

Using the graph that @Dan linked in his comment:

[image: circle with angles on it]

In this graph, y increases upward, and angles increase counter-clockwise. In an image, the coordinate system is flipped. This leads to counter-intuitive angles. Hence they invert the y axis to compute the angle.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not able to get what you write. `atan2` is able to return the result from `-PI` to `PI`... why do we still need to add the negative for it. Maybe you have another way to explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ggplayerlek: the gradient direction as computed in an image (i.e. without the minus) would point in a direction that you, as a user, would find wrong. Because a direction that you feel is +45 degrees would be computed as -45 degrees. They add the minus there to flip the angles, so that the value returned is intuitive for you. Another way to accomplish the same thing is putting the minus in front of `atan2` in that equation.

Answer (score 0):

Image coordinate has different basis compared to standard basis used by imgradient.

[image: Linear transform for image coordinate]

Introducing one more minus on Gy term for atan2() brings us with the same affect.